# Beautiful soup scrapes more than one images in a div but shows error on one image

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')  

images = [x ['src'] for x in soup.find("div",{"class":"rev-slider"}).find_all("img")]
```

This code run perfectly when the div has more than one image but in some pages there is only one image in this div so it stop working and showing this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I tried to add it in if else but not find any solution.

Comment: @baduker Can you please suggest me on this

Comment: it means `soup.find("div",{"class":"rev-slider"})` is returning `None`. You need to figure out how to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, your `soup.find("div",{"class":"rev-slider"})` is returning None. You need logic to handle it when that `<div>` and class is not present.

```
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')  

images = []
for x in soup.find("div",{"class":"rev-slider"}):
    try:
        images += [i['src'] for i in x.find_all("img")]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Now it showing this error:
line 652, in __getattr__self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: mind sharing the url where this is occuring? hard to debug without seeing whats going on

Comment: Or, I made an adjustment to the code. see if that helps

Comment: Can I skip this line of code if not found .rev-slider class on any page?

Comment: ya, essentionall thats what the try/except will do

Comment: I fixed it with try/except. Thank you so much for you help and suggestions.